# How to combine results into stream from multiple sources

Tags: scala, slick, reactive-streams

I use slick-3.0.0 and try to use [streaming](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/dbio.html#streaming).

Suppose there are `AccountsTable` and `PreferencesTable`:

I want to get some info from `PreferencesTable` and use it into stream from `AccountsTable`. For example (see TODO):

```
val somePrefQuery: Query[Rep[String], ...] = PreferencesTable.filter(...)
val somePrefAction = somePrefQuery.result
val somePrefStream = db.stream(somePrefAction)

val accountsStream: DatabasePublisher[String] = 
                              db.stream(AccountsTable.map(_.id).result)

accountsStream.mapResult { accountId: String =>
   //TODO how to get somePref value from 
   //     somePrefQuery or somePrefAction or somePrefStream
   // Is there best approach for such task?
   val somePref: String = ???

   val result:(String, String) = (accountId, somePref)
   result
}
```

Comment: Is there some sort of preferenceId within the account or vice versa, that would make a join within the query possible?

Comment: No, preferences are not connected with accounts. This is a synthetic example.   I want to get some result from some table and use it into another stream.

Comment: So what about using db.run on the somePrefAction and call map on the resulting future and then within that map, call mapResult on accountsStream. That would make somePrefResult accessible within your stream.

Comment: @thwiegan, good idea, thanks!

Comment: As an additional remark: You might want to look into stream processing with Akka Streams (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/). With that you might be able to solve your problem end2end with streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka provides [concurrent streaming functionality](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/index.html) that allows you to compose streams together in the manner that you described.

You first create a source of your `accountId` values:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source

val accountIdSrc : Source[String, _] = 
  Source fromPublisher (db stream (AccountsTable.map(_.id).result))
```

This `Source` can then be attached to the pref query logic:

```
def queryForPrefs(accountId : String) =
  PreferenceTable
    .filter(_.accountId === accountId)
    .map(_.pref)
    .result

case class PrefData(accountId : String, somePref : String)

val accountAndPrefSrc : Source[PrefData, _] = 
  accountIdSrc flatMapConcat { accountId =>
    Source
      .fromPublisher(db stream queryForPrefs(accountId))
      .map(pref => PrefData(accountId, pref))
  }
```